# Hyperlink space issue in rich text rte plugin in aem6.5

Tags: aem, aem-6

I have upload pdf file with “spaces” in them ex:20_YoungerBoyLetterheadv2 v1.pdf,
In text component,hyperlink with space character causing issue.

The hyperlink work using the path `/content/dam/abc/documents/men/20_YoungerBoyLetterheadv2 v1.pdf`
but when we enter full url `http://localhost:4502/content/dam/abc/documents/men/20_YoungerBoyLetterheadv2%20v1.pdf` hyperlink is not working as expected.

AEM is allowing users to upload files with “spaces” in them.
Using `AEM 6.5`.

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error you are  getting

Comment: Does this happen locally or only in staging/prod environments? Maybe there is a rewrite rule in front causing the issue.